# How to retrieve different dimension values from AWS CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I am using the below metric in a GraphMetric to create a widget in CloudWatch Dashboard.

```
return new Metric({
            namespace: 'MetricNamespace',
            metricName: 'MetricName',
            dimensionsMap: {
                "dimension1": "value"
            },
            statistic: Stats.percentile(90),
            label: 'Label',
            color: Color.BLUE,
            period: Duration.minutes(15),
            unit: 'Milliseconds'
        });
```

I have a dimension `dimension1` which produces multiple values based on the metric collected. Currently, I am hardcoding a list of values in my cdk code to loop over and create metrics based on different values of dimensions.

Is it possible to automatically retrieve this information from CloudWatch ? Given that CloudWatch metrics already has the different possible values of dimensions.

Comment: You can get metrics from cloudwatch and then sort out the dimensions, but you have an issue with order of operations.  the statistics won't exist until after the stack is created.  you'd have to wait some period of time before pulling the dimensions and then update the metrics.  That's a bad fit for one CDK stack.

Comment: @erik258 Assuming another stack exists which created the metrics. How can I access the all the dimensions?

Comment: Metrics are not resources, and you cannot create them with CDK, only reference them. Metrics are created when they are emitted to CloudWatch, so the order of operations does not matter. 
You can just pass the metric references from one stack to the other, though.